# Show that a function (the F-measure) of two monotonic functions (one increasing, one decreasing) has at most one maximum

Tags: real-analysis

This is a pure maths question that emerges from information retrieval.

The performance of an algorithm is typically measured with Precision and Recall, functions that vary between $0$ and $1$. These can then be combined into a single measure of effectiveness with a variable, $\beta$, that determines how much weight should be given to Precision and how much to Recall. This is called the $F_\beta$-measure, also varies between $0$ and $1$, and the formula is:

$$F_\beta = \frac{1 + \beta^2}{\beta^2 P + R} PR$$.

Typically, the algorithm developer can adjust the confidence threshold (also on the scale between $0$ and $1$) and generate readings for both Precision and Recall at each level. This will yield characteristic curves for Precision and Recall. One of the characteristics is that, as the threshold is raised, Precision is monotonically increasing and Recall is monotonically decreasing.

The question then is this:

**Assuming that Precision is monotonically increasing and Recall is monotonically decreasing, can we prove that $F_\beta$ has at most one maximum?**

Here is a typical chart of Precision, Recall and $F_\beta$ for a variety of values of $\beta$ where the y-axis shows the value of the function and the x-axis shows the confidence threshold:

[Click for chart of $F_\beta$ for various $\beta$ and Precision and Recall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hThQe.png)

Comment: If by "maximum" you mean "local maximum" the answer has to be *no*.

Comment: Can you say why? The illustrative diagram suggests otherwise.

Comment: Or even provide an example where this doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

The reciprocal of $F$ is a weighted sum of $1/R$ and $1/P$:$$\frac 1 F = \frac {\beta^2}{1+\beta^2} \frac 1 R + \frac 1 {1+\beta^2} \frac 1 P,$$ that is, a convex combination of an increasing function and a decreasing function.
In general, convex combinations of increasing and decreasing functions are not convex, not concave, and can have multiple local maxima and minima. The best that can be said of them in general is that they are of bounded variation.

For example (with $\beta=1$), suppose on a small neighborhood of $1/2$, $1/R(x) = x+\sin(Nx)/N^2$ (which is monotone increasing, and $1/P(x) = 1-x$ (which is monotone decreasing), when $N>1.$ On that neighborhood, $1/F(x) = \sin(Nx)/2N^2$, which (if $N$ is big enough) has multiple local maxima and minima.  So will $F$.

If you added the hypotheses that $1/R$ and $1/P$ were convex functions, then $1/F$ would be, too, and have (typically) a unique minimum, so $F$ would have a unique maximum.  I say *typically* because the minimum of $1/F$ (and maximum of $F$) might be attained on an interval.  I have no idea if adding this convexity hypothesis is reasonable in the field of "information retrieval", but it does lead to a simple and understandable proof of your desired conclusion.

Comment: Thank you so much @kimchilover! I see that my attempt to simplify the problem has failed. So now I have a more difficult question to ask:

What are the minimum conditions necessary for us to be confident that $F_ß$ has no more than one local maximum?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much. Those are indeed reasonable assumptions.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, give it an upvote.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if I have seemed ungrateful. In fact, I did try to vote for the reply already, but since this is my first time here it shows a message saying that the vote will be recorded but will not be shown. When I have more credit I will come back.